# disabled dropdownlist does not keep selected value on postback

Tags: asp.net, postback, html-select, disabled-control

I'm getting a weird behavior with a dropdownlist when I trigger a postback.

If the dropdownlist is enabled, the selected value remains the same after a postback.

However, if the dropdownlist is disabled (via a javascript when user ticks a checkbox), then the selected value is reset to the first item in the list.

How come ?

Comment: It would be better if you show what your code is doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to look up the value manually (probably store it in another field or so), and then set it yourself in the code behind. This is because if a control is disabled, the value would not be posted back to the sever.

Check out this question, and refer to the first answer by Pavan

[how to get selected value of Disabled dropdown in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687598/how-to-get-selected-value-of-disabled-dropdown-in-c-sharp)

> If you are trying to read the value of 2nd dropdown (disabled one) at
>   server, you will never be able to read the updated value, becuase data
>   in disabled controls will not be posted back to server from client

Comment: thanks for the information. I didn't know disabled controls didn't get their value posted back to the server.