# Disabling select option does not saves value in database

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a `Select` Option which I am disabling through  javascript like below

`document.getElementById('CmbDepartment').disabled = true;`

But after **disabing** what happens is, the value in the database is saved as `0`.

And after removing the **disable** part my value is getting saved properly.

> But I want to disable the `Select` list.

Here is my HTML of the `Select` list

```
<select id="CmbDepartment" runat="server" style="width: 25%" onchange="FunEmpFill()">
     <option value="0">--Select--</option>
</select>
```

So is there any other way to deal with this ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925716/disabled-form-fields-not-submitting-data

Comment: @NikhilGirraj: the link code is for textbox not for the `select` option.

Comment: The point is, `disabled` fields do not get submitted with the form.

Comment: @NikhilGirraj: yeah, I got that. SO what's the solution for that ?

Comment: so what you want in database column when your select is disabled . whether 0 or empty

Comment: @NazirUllah: there is value set which i want to save into the database

Comment: your issue is solved ?

Comment: You can use a hidden field to hold the selected value (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687598/how-to-get-selected-value-of-disabled-dropdown-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you have assigned option value as 0. and then disabled select tag, so it will take default option value.

You can change you option value or remove completely.

Or you can dynamically assign value to `select` tag and selected via JS

Ex

1. `$('#CmbDepartment').append($('<option>', {value:1, text:'One'}));`
2. `$('#CmbDepartment').append('<option val="1">One</option>');`
3. `var option = new Option(text, value); $('#CmbDepartment').append($(option));`

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose a hack.
Instead of disabling the select, I have set the style property `pointer-events` to `none`. Also, I added `opacity: 0.5;` to make it look disabled.
This would not stop the `select` control from being submitted along with the other form elements.

Try running the code snippet below.

```css
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
</select>

<button onClick="document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].classList.add('disabled');">Disable Select</button>
```

Comment: happy with ur logic, but will it would be **enable** whenever I need it ?

Comment: yes, just remove the class `. disabled ` from the element.

Comment: can u apply the same class on the `select` and show. As I dont want it on `button click`